# Reinstalling the phonegap app causes unable to receive push notifications while app is running

Tags: iphone, cordova, push-notification, sencha-touch-2, pushwoosh

I am creating an app using Phonegap 3.1, Sencha 2.3 for the platform android and iPhone.
For sending notification, i have used pushwoosh service and followed this link (http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-configuration-guide/)

Notification are getting perfectly on both Android and iPhone devices (whether app is running or not).

But the problem is, when I reinstall the app, **i am not able to get notifications when the app is running and notifications are getting when app is minimized or not running.**

In my index.html file, I have used this code to receive the notification while app is running.

```
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                          alert('push-notification');
                          var notification = event.notification;
                          navigator.notification.vibrate(1500);
                          navigator.notification.confirm(
                                    notification.aps.alert,  // message
                                    alertDismissed,         // callback
                                    'ThisApp',            // title
                                    'Done'                  // buttonName
                          );
                          pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);

});
function alertDismissed() {
                              //do something after Done button pressed
}
```

After reinstall the app this listener is not calling. 
I am not getting what actually missing in there, please advise.

Comment: Hey Avin, Did you get the reason for this weird thing?